# Can we have Sitecore XP like personalization in Content Hub

Tags: content-hub

We are evaluating options before suggesting `Content Hub` as the CMS platform for a client.
The website will be built with MVC and will not have Sitecore XP.

If we want to personalize the content for the end user (the user of the website and not `Content Hub`), like for example:
Showing a certain image based on user's location or
Showing a certain image based on user's authentication etc..

Is it possible OOB in `Content Hub` or does it have to be programmatically handled in the website business logic.

Comment: What are you building the actual website on?   In any case, personalisation could be driven by Sitecore Personalize or if you're using traditional Sitecore XP, using the regular Experience Platform tooling.

Comment: @MarkCassidy The website will be build on MVC. There will be no Sitecore XP. For the CMS, we are looking at Content Hub. So, will it have Sitecore like personalization OOB.

Comment: Content Hub is not a web CMS (in the sense you know from Sitecore XP etc). Sitecore Personalize however can be brought in to do personalisation; regardless of what drives the website. It's just not Content Hub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sitecore Content Hub platform is not a personalization engine. It is aimed at delivery and management of content and digital assets. Moving to Content Hub focuses purely on the content part of things in the composable DXP architecture.

As you seem to be moving that direction for architecture, you likely want to be looking at using a headless personalization engine which can provide that specific functionality. Sitecore has a product for that (Sitecore Personalize) as well as a CDP (Sitecore CDP) both based on the acquired Boxever technology. This can be one way to go. There are also lots of other vendors that have personalization tools, so if personalization is a business requirement you might want to look at what specifically you need to do, and at what scale, so you can find the right headless option to add to your content solution.